# Using tab key to move focus from data grid to next page element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accessibility, ag-grid, wcag2.0

Using AG-Grid, I need to be able to hit the tab key and have the focused element change from the grid/cell currently selected, to the next element on the page outside of the grid. The problem is that the tab key seems to be locked within the grid, and will not move outside of the data table to the next element.

I have an even listener on the cells that stores the last focused cell (used to store the last location to be able to tab back into the grid to the previously focused cell), but need to have the next focused cell be outside of the data grid:

```
const cells = document.getElementsByClassName('ag-cell');
[...cells].map(cell => {
  cell.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if(e.key === "Tab") {
      let lastCell = cell.attributes[2].value;
      console.log("Last Cell Focused: ", lastCell)
    }
  })
})
```

How can I remove the focus selection from the grid on keypress to the next focusable page element?

Here's a plnkr link to the current grid: [Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/cgkFVBEpJ9FxZ4jM1iIp?p=preview)

=====================================================

**UPDATE**

I've updated my code, and instead of attaching an event listener to every cell, it's now looking for the event triggered on the document. However, I'm still running into the issue that it's not getting the `last_cell` value and seeing the `focus-visible` class on `hasFocusVisible`.

```
//on arrow right if last_call === header that has 'focus-visible', set focus to first cell in body
const headerCells = document.getElementsByClassName('ag-header-cell-label');
const last_cell = headerCells[headerCells.length-1].attributes[2];
const hasFocusVisible = document.querySelector('.ag-header-cell-label').classList.contains('focus-visible');
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if(e.key === "ArrowRight") {
    // if(hasFocusVisible && last_cell) {
      console.log("EVENT TRIGGERED FROM: ", event.target, "Last Cell Value: ", last_cell, hasFocusVisible);
      //if last_call and 'ag-header-cell-label' has 'focus-visible', set focus to first cell in body
      const bodyCell = document.getElementsByClassName('ag-cell')[0];
    // }
  }
});
```

UPDATED Plnkr: [Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/JfJjQfeAHOciByV5TOwx?p=preview)

====================================================

**UPDATE 2**

I've updated the element selector to the following:

```
const last_cell = document.querySelector('.ag-header-cell:last-child');
const hasFocusVisible = document.querySelector('.ag-header-cell-label').classList.contains('.focus-visible');
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  console.log('document.activeElement', document.activeElement)
  const activeElement = document.activeElement;
  if(e.key === "ArrowRight" && activeElement) {
    if(last_cell) {
      console.log("EVENT TRIGGERED FROM: ", event.target, "Last Cell Value: ", last_cell, hasFocusVisible);
      //if last_call and 'ag-header-cell-label' has 'focus-visible', set focus to first cell in body
      const bodyCell = document.getElementsByClassName('ag-cell')[0];
    }
  }
  else if(e.key === "ArrowDown"){
    //look for first child in first row with same id as header and set focus
    document.querySelector('.ag-cell').focus();
  }
});
```

however, the `hasFocusVisible` variable is always coming up `false` when logging out the div that has the focus-visible class. I'm not sure if I have my logic incorrect, or its not able to get the `focus-visible` class on the `ag-header-cell-label` when the event listener is fired.

Comment: Is setting the `tabindex` HTML attribute not possible? Moz dev page for tabindex: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If tab works within the cells, don't add a listener to every cell, just add a single one to your document, and make it move focus to whatever you know is next on the page manually. For instance:

```js
var b = document.querySelector('button');
b.passThrough = true;
b.update = pass => {
  b.passThrough = pass;
  b.textContent = "click me to " + (b.passThrough ? "block" : "allow") + " tabbing";
}
b.addEventListener('click', e => b.update(!b.passThrough));
b.update(b.passThrough);

var focussable = Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll([
    'button',
    '[href]',
    'input',
    'select',
    'textarea',
    '[tabindex]:not([tabindex="-1"])'
  ].join(','))
);

// let's pretend this is your last cell.
var p = document.querySelector('p');

// make it kill off keydown events, BUT, also have it redirect focus
// to "the next focussable element", so you can see what that code looks like.
p.addEventListener('keydown', e => e.preventDefault());

document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if (b.passThrough && e.target === p) {
    var next = focussable.indexOf(p) + 1;
    focussable[next % focussable.length].focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<button>toggle</button>
<p tabindex=0>first</p>
<a href="#top">second</a>
<a href="#top">third</a>
```

Run this snippet, click the button, hit tab, notice that the tab event is now trapped (like in your cells). Now, click the button again, hit tab, hit tab again: notice it **seems** like the event is no longer trapped, when it fact it is: the event for the element itself is getting killed off, but the event listener for the *document* now explicitly moves focus for us.

Comment: Code snippet has an error on Internet Explorer.  It runs on Firefox and Chrome.  If you tab through the example without selecting the toggle button, to the share/edit/flag links after the example, then try to Shift+Tab back into the example, you get stuck between "first" and "second".

Comment: So adapt it. This is not me doing someone's work, this is me showing how that someone can do the work. (also note that IE10 and below are no longer supported or maintained, and so are irrelevant, with IE11 only running on machines that also run Edge, so if you need this to work on a website for normal users: this will work just  fine. If you have more specific requirements, needing to support dead/legacy browsers: the additional work you need to do there is 100% _your_ work to do)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I assume it would probably be best for performance and general good practice to not attach an event listener to every `ag-cell` element, since there could be hundreds or thousands. One of the big issues is how to have the event listener applied to the currently focused cell `ag-cell-focus` on tab key press and then push the focus to the next element outside of the grid.

Comment: The trick is you _don't_ attach it to the current cell, you attach it to the document, and let the handler check "which cell fired it off", using `event.target`, which is always the HTML element in which the event got generated. One handler, for a potential million cells, and it'll only need to refocus to outside your sheet on the last cell, for which you can use the convenient `:last-child` CSS pseudo-selector. Check whether `event.target` is that last cell, if not, do nothing. If so, move focus.

Comment: it's not my OP so i don't really care if it works or not.  was just pointing out what didn't work in case someone tries to implement it.  and it was ie 11 that didn't work.  still a very popular browser and sometimes out of a users control if they're on a work computer that doesn't allow updates very often (such as government)

Comment: Again: if anyone has to support legacy/dead browsers, then they can search stackoverflow for solutions for those specific browsers, after looking at this answer and going "cool, except this part here doesn't work, let's search for how to implement that for legacy/dead browsers".

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - Thanks for your input about moving the event listener to the document. I've adjusted my code (as seen in the updated question), but still experiencing issues getting both the `last_cell` and checking that it has the `focus-visible` class in order to move the focus to the first body cell. Any thoughts?

Comment: You want to start using document.querySelector to find the elements you need. In this case, `e = document.querySelector('.ag-cell:last-child');` to get the, by definition, last cell. Checking for the class is then using `e.classList.contains('focus-visible')`

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - I've updated my code in the latest edit, but running into what I think comes down to a pure logic issue checking if the focus state is on the active element.

Comment: I'm not here to help you write all your code, though - the answer + comments so far explain how to deal with that tab key (not arrow keys or anything else) as originally asked about. If you're getting stuck on "determining if an element has focus", that's a different question entirely, and something for which there are already answers to be found on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - appologies. I recently realized I was diverting from the original question, dealing with multiple issues with AG-Grid. Only looking for guidance or a suggestion/tip :)

Comment: May I also recommend hitting that "this was a useful answer" and/or "this answered my question" checkmark, since that's what Stackoverflow surfaces information based on =) To see if any element is the currently focussed element, compare it to `document.activeElement`.